# SQL bringing two tables into a existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables and I want to bring over the data onto a single existing table that has columns for the inputs.

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`customer`
(`CUST_ID`,
`CUST_NM`,
`CUST_INCOME_AM`,
`CUST_STREET_AD`,
`CUST_POSTAL_CD`,
`CUST_NO`,
`CUST_CITY_NM`,
`CUST_STATE_CD`,

`CUST_PHONE_NO`,
`CUST_BIRTH_DT`)
```

WHERE ODS_SALE_LARGE contains `CUST_NM`,`CUST_STREET_AD`,`CUST_POSTAL_CD`,`CUST_NO`,`CUST_CITY_NM`,`CUST_STATE_CD`,
`CUST_PHONE_NO`,`CUST_BIRTH_DT`

and ODS_CUSTOMER has `CUST_ID`,`CUST_NO`,`CUST_INCOME_AM`

How do I bring these two tables together?

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`customer`
(`CUST_ID`,
`CUST_NM`,
`CUST_INCOME_AM`,
`CUST_STREET_AD`,
`CUST_POSTAL_CD`,
`CUST_NO`,
`CUST_CITY_NM`,
`CUST_STATE_CD`,

`CUST_PHONE_NO`,
`CUST_BIRTH_DT`)

select distinct
ods_customer.*,
s.CUST_NM,
s.CUST_STREET_AD,s.CUST_POSTAL_CD,s.CUST_CITY_NM,s.CUST_STATE_CD,
s.CUST_PHONE_NO, s.CUST_BIRTH_DT
FROM ods_customer
JOIN ods_customer AS c
ON c.CUST_NO = customer.CUST_NO
join ods_sale_large as s
on s.CUST_NO = customer.CUST_NO
```

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query that joins the two tables.

Comment: yes i understand that is how i need to do it but how would I set it up. Which join would I need?

Comment: The common column appears to be `CUST_NM`, so join on that.

Comment: You don't need to join `ods_customer` with itself.

Comment: ok i switched out where s.cust_no with s.cust_nm and I get the error that it is a unknown column

Comment: `customer.CUST_NO` is unknown because you're not joining with `customer`, that's the table you're inserting into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join `ods_customer` with itself. Just join it with `ods_sales_large`.

The join should be on the `CUST_NM` columns, since that's the only thing in common between the two input tables.

You can't reference `customer` table in the `SELECT` query, since that's the table you're inserting into, not where you're selecting from.

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`customer`
(`CUST_ID`, `CUST_NM`, `CUST_INCOME_AM`,
`CUST_STREET_AD`, `CUST_POSTAL_CD`, `CUST_NO`, `CUST_CITY_NM`, `CUST_STATE_CD`, `CUST_PHONE_NO`, `CUST_BIRTH_DT`)

select distinct
c.CUST_ID, c.CUST_NM, c.CUST_INCOME_AM,
s.CUST_STREET_AD, s.CUST_POSTAL_CD, s.CUST_NO, s.CUST_CITY_NM, s.CUST_STATE_CD, s.CUST_PHONE_NO, s.CUST_BIRTH_DT
FROM ods_customer AS c
join ods_sale_large as s
on s.CUST_NM = c.CUST_NM
```

Comment: ok i have entered this into the code and now I'm getting error code 1054 unknown column `c.CUST_NM`

Comment: I don't understand why. You wrote: ODS_CUSTOMER has CUST_ID, CUST_NM, CUST_INCOME_AM

Comment: Is that wrong about the columns in `ODS_CUSTOMER`?

Comment: Im sorry, the ods_customer has Cust_no, not Cust_nm I've changed that out with the NM but now I get s.cust_no is unknown on clause

Comment: i found the problem causing that one as well. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you also get the list of columns in `ods_sales_large` wrong? Please update the question with the output of `show create table ods_sales_large` and `show_create table ods_customer`